# Which solr version i should install on server for best compatible to typo3 7.6.4?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a problem regarding the solr search on typo3. I have asked an expert he said you have wrong solr version on server because of that pages are not indexing.

Can anyone let me know which version of solr search best for typo3(7.6.4)?

Comment: It depends on which features typo makes use of, but in general, Solr is usually backwards compatible across most releases, so 6.1 _should_ work, but the schema might need to be tweaked a bit (and seeing as the default is to use the managed schema, that might be confusing). What errors are you getting when you're indexing?

Comment: @MatsLindh I was facing indexing issues for pages which are having plugin attached to get dynamic data based on parameters.

Comment: When i check report log then i can see this error:
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception:
Solr response does not appear to be valid JSON, please examine the raw response with getRawResponse() method

Comment: It would be more interesting to see the log at the Solr side, as that is where the error is generated.

Comment: Yes.. i can see logs http://awesomescreenshot.com/01662l3578

Comment: This is still the TYPO logs and not the Solr logs.

Comment: Is issue because of solr installed version. One mentor suggested me to install 
 * TYPO3 CMS: 7.6.x (LTS) / dev-master
    * Apache Solr: 4.10.4
    * Solr plugins:
        * solr-typo3-plugin-1.3.0.jar
    * Add-ons:
        * EXT:tika: master
        * EXT:solrgrouping: master
        * EXT:solrfal: master

Answer (score 2):

For TYPO3 v7.6.4 Solr Search versions are: 4.0.0, 4.0.2, 5.0.0
You can check the version history by yourself on this link:
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/solr

And then click on the download tab.

On the server part the version to be used for TYPO3 7.6.x is 
Apache Solr 4.10.
Here is a list of server versions:
https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Supported_Solr_versions

Comment: i have installed solr 5.0 on typo3 7.6.4, i was asking about apache solr version on server.

Comment: what possible solution for this error. 
When i check report log then i can see this error: Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Solr response does not appear to be valid JSON, please examine the raw response with getRawResponse() method

Comment: This problem can be an issue with the usage of POST data as a default HTTP method.A workaround is to select "GET" as the "HTTP method" under solr server settings.
Further investigation would be done by:

1. Install a devlog extension.
2. Enable raw GET and raw POST logging in TS.
3. Run the task
4. See log messages in AdminTools>devLog

Comment: Unfortunatly, deveLog is not available for typo3 7.6.x

Comment: OK, i have installed another develog extension then i can see some dev logs here:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/01662l3578

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted/`

The correct URL should be `http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/`.

I just did that and problem has been solved regarding wrong json response.